# cant upload an image file

Tags: php, html

I have got this:

```
<input type="file" name="image">


 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

{

```
 if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']))
 {

     $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
 }
 else
 {

    $error= 'Error: no image was set ';

 }
```

basically, it tells me that the image, name doesnt exist doesnt exist..why is that?

```
 {

    $error= 'Error: no image was set ';

 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your FORM have an enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute?

```
<form name="xyz" action="myscript.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

EncType attribute is used to tell the browser how to post the data to the server. If you don't use a multipart mime type, the data can't be sent to the server correctly.

Multipart looks like this:

```
boundary:xyz
====xyz====
name: field1
content-type: text/plain
content-lenght: 10
1234567890

====xyz====
name: field2
content-type: text/plain
content-lenght: 10
1234567890

====xyz====
name: field3
content-type: text/plain
content-lenght: 10
1234567890
```

You don't have to send it yourself, just set the enctype, and all that magic is done for you.